# Amplituhedron without SUSY

Tags: supersymmetry, amplituhedron

I was reading around about the [Amplituhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplituhedron) (there are many topics on this SE or in other places for discussions outside this), and I was wondering, is supersymmetry required to make it work or to define it?

I find the quest to geometrize anything wonderful, and this object would be really useful if with it we could calculate things which actually exist in nature.

Answer (score 2):

> [When the volume of the amplituhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplituhedron) is calculated in the planar limit of N = 4 D = 4 supersymmetric Yang–Mills theory, it describes the scattering amplitudes of subatomic particles. The amplituhedron thus provides a more intuitive geometric model for calculations whose underlying principles were until then highly abstract.

So it  seems that supersymmetry is part of the recipe and particle interactions are the result of the calculations.

From a recent paper :

> [This provides us](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08208) with the first non-trivial results on scattering
>   amplitudes in the theory valid for arbitrarily many loops and external particle multiplicities.